# Присоеденение boost к CMake

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, linux-mint

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost) - ищет boost по стандартному пути `/usr/local/`, мой boost лежит по пути `/home/cheshirecat/libs` Как сделать так, чтобы FIND_PACKAGE(Boost) нашел  boost?

Мой CmakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(BoostTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(BoostTest main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( BoostTest ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016448/how-can-i-get-cmake-to-find-my-alternative-boost-installation

Answer (score 0):

```
export BOOST_ROOT=/home/cheshirecat/libs/boost_1_67_0
```